# I have this issue.. ERROR: Failed to parse XML in

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dependencies, manifest

**I have this problem and can't fix it, can someone please help me with that? It is for an Android Studio project: ERROR: Failed to parse XML in /Users/kevinhomorales/Todi/iMarket for Android/Todi/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[8,5]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app**

Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.kevinhomorales.todijava">


  //Permisos

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNETt"/>

  //Permisos

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_key"/>



    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Launch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Categories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Information"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Tutorial"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Table"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kevinhomorales.todijava.Cart"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

Dependency

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

  defaultConfig {

    applicationId 'com.kevinhomorales.todijava'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-     rules.pro'
      }
  }

 }

 dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1' // Independencia para el slide del   tutorial
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
 }
```

Comment: Which line in manifest r u getting that error?

Comment: Yes! There! I have issue

Comment: There means where.. Which line?

Comment: The first line I have issue

Comment: If you have commented line in manifest remove it

Comment: Oh! Great! It's works!

Comment: Thank u so much Android_id!